# Implicit resolution for different orders of case class and companion

Tags: scala, implicit, case-class, companion-object, context-bound

Usually, I write first a `case class` and then the companion `object` in the same file, right below. But when trying to import an `implicit` declared in the companion, I'm forced to switch the order of declaration (and I don't want, obviously). What is the recommended practice to overcome this situation?

For a concrete case, the following code doesn't work:

```
  object SomeLib {
     def doSomething[T : List](t: T) = "meh"
  }

  case class FooWorker(x: String) {
    import FooWorker._ // bring the implicit in scope for doSomething
    def then(event: String) : FooWorker = {
      copy(x = SomeLib.doSomething(event)) // requires implicit
    }
  }

  object FooWorker {
    implicit val list = List("a", "b", "c")
  }
```

But if I declare `object FooWorker` before `case class FooWorker` it does work. I'm using Scala 2.11.6 and SBT to test. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TravisBrown I'm not using the REPL. I have sbt project with a single `Main.scala` file with this inside and a simple driver to test it. I'm running it directly from the console (i.e. `sbt run`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that the implicit `FooWorker.list` does not have an explicitly declared type. If you complete the line to:

```
implicit val list: List[String] = List("a", "b", "c")
```

everything works as expected, regardless of order of declarations. In general, you should always give an explicit type for an implicit value. This rule will be enforced in a future version of Scala.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves the issue. Out of curiosity: why the explicit typing changes the situation at all? Aren't the implicits resolved after the types are known (explicitly or inferred)?

Answer (score 2):

This is an open bug.

See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5197 (and related/duplicate issues).